# Why is my data is not writing to Firebase - App crashes due to setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

for the past two weeks i've been having a struggle to write data to firebase, although the tutorials seem so simple :/....My app has a view controller and a tableview controller. users can add an event Title, event date and description (strings) and add a picture as well. Whenever i try to run the simulator it crashes on me! See code below. Please please help me out this is really getting frustrating.. Even if I place breakpoints in the code on top it crashes.. If someone can help me in a chat that would be awesome or maybe send the file to cause its been too long seriously I need an answer so i understand the problem.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI

class EventViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

//outlets for text & image
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var eventName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var eventDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var eventDes: UITextView!

//Database connection
let rootref = FIRDatabase().reference()
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func submitEvent(sender: AnyObject) {

    let name = eventName.text
    let date = eventDate.text
    let text = eventDes.text
    var data: NSData = NSData()
    var user = NSDictionary()//declare here

    if let image = photoImageView.image {
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.1)!
    }

    let base64String = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    if let unwrappedName = name , unwrappedDate = date, unwrappedText = text{
        //use your declared dictionary
        user = ["name":unwrappedName, "date":unwrappedDate, "text":unwrappedText, "photoBase64":base64String]
    }


    //Add firebase child node
    //let event = FIRDatabase().reference().child(name!)
    //Do not create one more reference to database

    rootref.child(name!)
    rootref.child(name!).setValue(user)


    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}

    //UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        photoImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

@IBAction func addPicture(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)) {
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint to get the location of the crash

Comment: I tried but it doesn't matter where i put the breakpoint it keeps on crashing regardless of where i put the breakpoint even before view did load

Comment: It keeps going back to my Delegate and show Thread 1 signal SIGABRT. plus the error log shows 2016-06-29 09:30:54.468 App[25294:1972640] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x03673a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
 1   libobjc.A.dylib   0x04108e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
 2   CoreFoundation     0x0355c174 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 948
 3   CoreFoundation    0x035db114 -[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKeyed etc.....

Comment: The error message says that somewhere an `nil` value is set in a mutable dictionary using the method `setObject:forKey:`, which is not allowed. It seems that the error occurs not ih the code you've posted.

Comment: @vadian I have the viewcontroller disconnected from all the other controllers. Plus i run the simulator with this viewcontroller as the initial view. So how can it crash? It should crash because of this code right? Im getting desperate here..anyone else has a updated firbase tutorial for populating tableviews

Comment: Maybe it's the line including `setValue(user)`. Is it useful to execute the line even if the optional binding is failing? Fact is, somewhere there is a `nil` value assigned to a mutable dictionary which causes the crash. In the stack trace there might be the method call where the crash occurred.

Comment: Tried to remove that but the app keeps crashing..plan B roght will be to redo the entire code from scratch..does ANYONE know an updated tutorial of firebase and tableviews? The one of Ray is outdated and it confuses my learning proces.